# Masked contour plot in python without filler between True-False

Tags: python, matplotlib, mask, contour

I would like to draw a single contourline from a masked array.

The problem is matplotlib draws several lines in the "unknown" area between True and False and not a single line.

It doesn't matter if the line is in the middle or on the edge of True or False, so in the simple example below, I would like a single line in either Y=1, Y=2 or Y=1.5.

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

Y = np.array([0,1,2,3])

Z_mask = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False],
                   [False, False, False, False, False],
                   [True, True, True, True, True],
                   [True, True, True, True, True]])

plt.contour(X,Y,Z_mask)           

plt.show()
```

Image plot example
[image: Image plot example]

I have tried the different keyword arguments for plt.contour but none of them seems to do the job.

Comment: I have found an ugly workaround. If I convert my masked array to 0 and 1's, I can use the following to get the desired result.
    plt.contour(X, Y, Z_mask, levels=[0.5]). 
I would still appreciate a solution on how to use the masked array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell `contour` how many levels to plot using a forth argument:

From the docs:

> `contour(X,Y,Z,N)`
>
> contour up to N automatically-chosen levels.

So for your plot:

```
plt.contour(X,Y,Z_mask,1)
```

Produces:

[image]

---

Sidenote: For your 'workaround' in your comment above, there is no need to convert your mask array from `False` and `True` to `0` and `1`, as in `python`, booleans are just a subclass of integers:

```
In [14]: False == 0
Out[14]: True

In [15]: True == 1
Out[15]: True
```